# How to assign Data to Datatable with Combobox Datasource?

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable, datasource

I am binding data to combobox with a datatable(dt1) in a method called IsDatafill.

```
combobox.DataSource=dt1;
combobox.DisplayMember="Col_1";
combobox.ValueMember="Col_2";
```

and bringing some more data with that datatable(dt1) like col_3,col_4; so i use this data in another event is selectedIndexChanged event. so here i have a datatable(dt2). here i want to assign data to this by using

```
datatable dt2=combobox.DataSource;
```

Its giving error how to i use like this..., error is given below

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Data.DataTable dt2=(System.Data.DataTable)combobox.DataSource;
```

You have to cast it since the DataSource property is of type object